# Benefits from importing UIKit.UIViewController instead of importing the whole framework

Tags: swift, xcode12

I have noticed that it is possible (in Xcode 12, at least) to do:

```
import UIKit.ViewController

class ViewController: UIViewController {}
```

Up until now I have always done `import UIKit`.

Does someone know which benefits one has from importing only the class? Does the app build/compile faster?

Thanks

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://nshipster.com/import/#clarifying-and-minimizing-scope).

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper, quite disappointing that it is only helpful "to clarify your intent as a programmer". I had hoped improved building times.

Comment: @regina_fallangi Just to note, it's not Xcode12 feature, this has been available since ever. Yes, no build time optimizations but it really improves code readability as said in the link 

Comment: @Ratz that’s a subjective matter, I’d say. Yes, it improves readability if you only need top 3-5 views. The moment you import more than 5 things, it starts to represent clutter. One can quickly end up with Java-like files where one has headers that can be 20-30 lines of code until one sees logic :)

Comment: @regina_fallangi Yes completely agree. It's depends on usage and the component.